# Automating Google image search

Tags: scripting, web

I am using a raspberry Pi at the moment and I would like to acheive the following.

1. Every hour an automated Google Image search of a specific predefined term.
2. The image is then downloaded to the Pi
3. The Pi then prints the image.

Comment: 1) every hour -> see `cron` jobs ; 2) search and save hit as described over at [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27909521/download-images-from-google-with-command-line) ; 3) print as in printing on paper? -> `lpr` (or `lp`). General hints: use `man command` to learn more about command and also check stackoverflow and askubuntu as your problem might be solved there. Now it's about making your first steps in writing a shell script. Have fun!

Comment: Much appreciated Fiximan : )